# How to use or inherit 2 models classes fields in one model class in Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created 2 different model classes, I want to use both models fields in a specific model.

```
user_types = (("Agent", "Agent"), ("Branch", "Branch"), ("Company", "Company"))


class CommonModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-created_at', '-updated_at']



class PersonType(models.Model):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=user_types, blank=False)


class UserData(CommonModel, PersonType):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But I am getting an error when I am trying to access admin models page
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/mysite/userdata/

> Internal Server Error: /admin/mysite/userdata/ Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/home/shiv/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column
>   mysite_userdata.created_at does not exist LINE 1: ...,
>   "mysite_userdata"."usertype_ptr_id", "mysit...
>                                                                ^
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

How can I fix it?

Comment: please, re-run your migrations, that shall resolve.

Comment: ok that worked but not showing PersonType models field not showing in UserDatamodel admin page

Comment: please check if your db has the person type data